# Element objects vs HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is pretty simple, and it may be subjective.  For the most part when I am manipulating the DOM, I create HTML text and append it to an element.  Sometimes, if the data is small enough, I will create elements and append those to the parent element.

```
$("#p").html("<p>My Paragraph</p>");
```

OR

```
$("<p/>").html("My Paragraph").appendTo("#p");
```

Which of these should be used and why?

Comment: IMO, I belive the first should be faster since you're only calling 1 function instead of two.

Comment: They're both fine to use. Are you looking for speed differences?

Comment: Matter of preference ... looking for speed differences on those is being a bit paranoid ...

Comment: http://jsperf.com/appending-dom-jquery-vs-native-append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has an even more elegant way to create elements:

```
var $p = $("<p/>", {
    html: "My paragraph"
}).appendTo("#p");
```

The biggest value to creating elements is that you can save references to them, then use them however you need. No need to find them again using a `$()` selector.

If, on the other hand, your HTML is very simple and you don't need to access any of those elements later on, it's fine to use the `.html()` method. And it's slightly faster.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that syntax existed!

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice syntax that was introduced in 1.4: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use the first since it depends on the structure of your page, whereas the second one has to do with the content which is more likely to change. I do not know about performance, if that is more what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, I just plain don't like the look of the second option. Semantically, you should never see `<p/>` anywhere in markup, so it feels weird to use it (even though I know it's populated before being added to the DOM). The first example looks much cleaner.

Purely a matter of preference, and I'm a strong advocate of code readability over optimisation until you can actually perceive a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
$("#p").html("<p>My Paragraph</p>");
```

is the fastest method.
see http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-order